# how to retrieve sql error logs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am trying to get sel server error logs. i search so much on net but do not get much info.

is any how event log is been useful for it?[here is the link for event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_hmm_windows_event_log)

i find path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log where SQL logs is been save in a file.i want to retieve this with vc++

In registery what is a path for this file like (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\)..if there is any API for it than also kindly suggest me a link..